# Python subprocess stdout.readlines() getting stuck

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, sudo

I am trying to use to python subprocess module in order to ssh to a server and then switch to a super user and then ls and print the folders in the terminal.

My Code:

```
def sudo_Test():
    HOST = 'Host'
    PORT = '227'
    USER = 'user'
    cmd='sudo su - ec2-user;ls'

    process = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','-tt','{}@{}'.format(USER, HOST),
                            '-p',PORT,cmd],
                           shell=False,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.stdin.write("my_password\r\n")

    print "stuck here VVV"
    result = process.stdout.readlines()
    print "finished it"

    if not result:
        print "Im an error"
        err = process.stderr.readlines()
        print('ERROR: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print "I'm a success"
        print result

print sudo_Test()
```

Console output when I run this:

```
dredbounds-computer:folder dredbound$ python terminal_test.py
stuck here VVV
```

For some reason the code gets stuck on the line result = process.stdout.readlines(). I have to cntrl+c to exit out of the terminal session when this happens. It works fine if I just do cmd='sudo; ls' instead of cmd='sudo su - ec2-user;ls'.Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how I can get this to work?

Update:
I changed cmd='sudo su - ec2-user;ls' -> cmd='sudo su - ec2-user ls' in the code above. Now I am getting the following error:

```
['password\r\n', '\r\n', '/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary   file\r\n']
```

I'm not sure why it thinks ls is a binary file now, but is there anyway i can tell it that it is just a terminal command so it returns a list of directories?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
sudo su - ec2-user;ls
```

`sudo su - ec2-user` opens a shell and *waits* for input.  You need to send the shell an exit command (or close its stdin) before the shell exits and the `ls` command is run.

**If your goal was to run `ls` as user `ec2-user`**, then try:

```
sudo -u ec2-user ls
```

In other words, replace

```
cmd='sudo su - ec2-user;ls'
```

With:

```
cmd='sudo -u ec2-user ls'
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried this and now I'm getting the following error:

    ['my_password\r\n', '\r\n', '/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file\r\n']

If I just run "sudo -u ec2-user ls" in the terminal without code I also get the error:
"bin/ls: cannot execute binary file"

Comment: Because your question is tagged `Linux`, it is odd that you are getting DOS line-endings, `\r\n`, in your output.  Is there more about your setup that you should tell us?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm working on a mac (OS X El Capitan). If I do sudo su manually to ec2-user and then ls it works.